# To Display the values in the table field Bus-time based on current time in android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

My Problem is I need to display all the data in the database based on the field Bus-Time with a comparison with the current time i.e if the current time is 6:30 PM then it should display all the Bus-time field value that is greater than or equal to the current time(6:30).

I had written an SQL query in DatabaseHandler.java in android studio but I am getting error in the query can you help to resolve it out.

The code for the query is.

```
public List<Contact> getBus(String t)
    {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE CAST( bus_time AS TIME ) >= CAST(" + t +" AS TIME )";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;


    }
```

The Error I am getting is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.database, PID: 4539
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":27": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE CAST( bus_time AS TIME ) >= CAST(18:27 AS TIME )
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: What is the format of the column `bus_time` in the table?

Comment: The format of bus_time is string

Comment: And The values are {"8:00","18:00","20:00"}

Comment: What about the minutes? Are there always 2 digits?

Comment: Yes, I used only 2 digits. the code that i used to get current time is

Comment: Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat simpDate;
        simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
        String t = simpDate.format(d);
        time.setText(simpDate.format(d));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite there is no data type `TIME` and any date and/or time values should be treated as `TEXT`.
Use the function `STRFTIME()` to get the current time in format `HH:MM`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
WHERE SUBSTR('0' || bus_time, -5) >= STRFTIME('%H:%M', 'now', 'localtime')
```

If you saved the time in the column `bus_time` in format `HH:MM` (with 2 digits for the hour), you would not need the function `SUBSTR()` which pads at the left a `0` if the hour has only 1 digit and the code would be:

```
WHERE bus_time >= STRFTIME('%H:%M', 'now', 'localtime')
```